# Independent Gaussian Assumption in MA(q) process

Tags: regression, time-series, gaussian-process, moving-average-model

In our statistics course we are learned about MA(q) models.

$\epsilon_{t} = X_{t} + \theta_{0}\epsilon_{t-1} + ... + \theta_{q}\epsilon_{t-q}$

But if we think about regression, more like the AR(p) process, if the parameters that are estimated are larger, then this implies that a covariate has a large effect on the response.

My question is: How can we say that the current error is dependent on the past errors if we assume a White Noise gaussian process such that $\epsilon_{t} - IN(0, \sigma_e^{2}) $ for all time. If we had to create a correlation matrix for all the errors it would be diagonal with this independence assumption, so how can we use the past errors, independent of the current, to model the current error?

I am not sure when the errors are random and when they are fixed as my course notes don't make a distiction between the cases.

Any explanation will be appretiated.

Comment: What do you mean by *how can we build a model [that says the errors can be modelled as the sum of the past errors]*?

Comment: Hi: The errors in an ARIMA model are always random ( with some distribution that usually assumed normal )  before you see them. But, once the error is observed, then you can view it as fixed. I doubt this answers your question but it's not very  clear to me what your question is.

Comment: @mlofton, just that we are modelling an error from previous errors, but it is not clear to me how we can do this if we in the first place assume that the errors are independent?

Comment: Hi: the errors can be independent OF EACH OTHER but that doesn't mean that they can't be used to say something about the response. Suppose there was some odd process that flipped directions at each $t$ ALWAYS. Then, if you use  $\alpha \epsilon_{t-1}$ as a predictor that would be a reasonable predictor  ( if $\alpha$ is estimated and comes back negative ).